# Using proxy to over come cross domain restriction

Tags: apache-flex, apache, tomcat, proxy, cross-domain

After reading James Ward's [post](http://www.jamesward.com/2009/11/08/how-bad-crossdomain-policies-expose-protected-data-to-malicious-applications/) I'm considering using a proxy rather than a crossdomain.xml file. I have a java app, which includes a flex applet, on one tomcat instance and a java web service on another tomcat instance.  Does it make sense to have a single (Apache httpd) proxy handle requests for both the app and the web service, thus eliminating the cross domain restriction?

Other suggestions/recommendations on how to deal with the cross domain issue are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many people serve their Flex app from the same domain as their services to avoid the need for crossdomain policies and proxies.  For my sites I have Apache httpd in front of Tomcat (via mod_proxy but mod_ajp would be fine too).  The SWF file is served from Tomcat while the services are served from Tomcat through mod_proxy.

Comment: If the services are served from Tomcat through mod_proxy, shouldn't the SWF file be served via mod_proxy as well? By serving the SWF from Tomcat but serving the services through mod_proxy doesn't that cause a same-origin conflict?

Comment: You can do it that way but you don't have to since mod_proxy can be setup on a path like /services while Apache httpd still serves /.  That way it won't be a cross-domain request from the app to /services.

Answer (score 1):

A proxy used to unify the two services is probably the cleanest way to do it, but I highly recommend [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) for the proxy as it's really lightweight, fast, and easy to set up.